# db2 stored procedures creation behavior

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am playing with db2 stored procedures and I am struggling in understading the following concept.
When I create a stored procedure like the simple below

```
create or replace procedure test()
begin
insert into mytable(a) values ('a');
insert into mytable(a) values ('b');
insert into mytable(a) values ('c');
end
```

I can see that the mytable gets filled during this creation.
I was expecting to use 'call test()' to insert my data, but I can see it is not what I thought. What I am doing wrong here or it does work like this?

To avoid this odd behavior I found that I need to put everything on the same line and I have what I expect i.e. no data inserted when I call any "create or replace procedure"

```
create or replace procedure test() begin insert into mytable(a) values ('a'); insert  into mytable(a) values ('b');  insert into mytable(a) values ('c');     end
```

Comment: Are you inputting this on the command line? If so you need to escape the new line characters. Better still put all your definitions in a file and process the complete file.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: I am already doing this. That code is in a file called test.sql and I use the following command 'db2 -v -t -f test.sql -m -z xti.out'. ONce again it looks like it execute those line as they are read.

Comment: Please indicate in your question or tags that this is a question regarding DB2 LUW.  This behavior does not apply to other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the termination character for each instruction.

For example, if you have a script file called test.sql with inserts and a stored procedure definition, then your defintion will be:

test.sql

```
insert into mytable (a) values ('a')@
create procedure test ()
  begin
    insert into mytable (a) values ('b');
  end@
```

And you will execute the script via this command

```
 db2 -td@ -f test.sql
```

The @ sign indicates the termination character (option -td@ to indicate the Termination character Delimiter). Note that this is different that ; (semi colon) because the ; is used as termination character inside a routine (stored procedure, udf, trigger).

As you can see, the 'a' value will be inserted in the first insert. The 'b' value will be inserted from the stored procedure.

In order o be sure what you inserted, ou can query the DB2 catalog in order to see the defined stored procedures, and the 'bodies'.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `-t` option, which specifies that `;` is the statement terminator.

You can't use a semicolon as the statement terminator when writing procedures or other blocks of code, because the whole procedure declaration needs to be considered as a single statement.  DB2 is breaking it up into multiple statements based on semicolons.

Set the statement terminator to something else [using the `-tdX` option](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010409.html).  I use `!` as my standard statement terminator in DB2, and it works well for me (it is not used in DB2 syntax except for `!=`, which can be replaced by `<>`).

Making this change should fix your problem.

I am surprised that putting it on a single line made it work, though, as I wouldn't expect that to make any difference (there is an option to automatically treat lines as statement terminators, but you don't have it on).