# Error while creating a simple DB2 sql procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, zos

I am trying to create a db2 procedure on DB2 z/OS 10.1.5. The code I am using is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WSDIWW16.CALCULATE_SALARY()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
update wsdiww16.emptable
set dailywage = dailywage * 30;
END;
```

I am getting sqlcode - 104

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<END-OF-STATEMENT>" was found following "". 
Expected tokens may include:  "DECLARE".
```

I haven't created an sql procedure earlier. Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [db2 stored procedures creation behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939165/db2-stored-procedures-creation-behavior)

Comment: This is not working for db2 zOs

Comment: CHeck out http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21568227

Answer (score 0):

You've got two semicolons in that CREATE statement. The first one needs to be a different character that's recognized as a statement terminator.

What development environment are you using? In Rational Developer for z, you can right-click the editor and select the Set Statement Terminator option:

[image: RDz]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYgbu.jpg)

Similar options should be available in Data Studio, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use end line terminator such as '/' and execute your query using below command -

db2 +c -td/ -vf SQL_file_name

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The answer with the graphical menu worked for me.  From inside my SQL script I did a right click anywhere in the white space.  The menu above then appeared.  I then left clicked on "Set Statement Terminator" (as requested).  I then changed my terminator character to "#" (no quote marks).  After that the semicolon character ";" started working again.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to end your procedures with a '/'.