# table creation procedure DB2

Tags: db2

I have created a procedure like the one below. i know PL SQL a bit but i am new to DB2.
when i execute the below procedure getting an error that the use of reserve keyoword end is invalid.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  WLM ENVIRONMENT FOR DEBUG MODE #TTCOM
  ASUTIME NO LIMIT

BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
  DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_STATE CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42704';
  DECLARE tname VARCHAR(5000);
 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_STATE BEGIN
  END;
   
FOR i AS SELECT tablename FROM EWPS.tablelist
DO
tname = 'create table '+i.tablename+'_2112 like '+i.tablename+';' ;
tname1 = 'insert into '+i.tablename+'_2112 (select * from '+i.tablename+');';
call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(tname)
execute immediate tname;
execute immediate tname;
--set tname=i.tablename
END FOR;
--RETURN tname ;
--COMMIT;

END test;
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: What version and platform of Db2? If LUW, is the Oracle compatibility mode enabled? What is the exact error message? What is the statement terminator?

Answer (score 0):

You need two differnt terminators - one for the statements within the procedure and one for the CREATE PPROCEDURE itself.

Check out this command to set a terminator

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
```

And also chekc out this [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939165/db2-stored-procedures-creation-behavior)

Comment: where should i use the terminator in the procedure? sorry if i am asking a basic question

Comment: All ";" besides the last one in your example/question are terminators of statements within the procedure - the last one is the terminator of the CREATE statement itself - these need to be different. Hope tht helps

Comment: is this right?
CREATE PROCEDURE test() 
BEGIN
  
  DECLARE tname VARCHAR(5000);
 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_STATE BEGIN
  END;
   
FOR i AS SELECT tablename FROM EWPS.tablelist
DO
tname = 'create table '+i.tablename+'_2112 like '+i.tablename+';' ;
tname1 = 'insert into '+i.tablename+'_2112 (select * from '+i.tablename+');';
call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(tname)
execute immediate tname;
execute immediate tname;

END FOR;

end;

END test@;